# Reading Rails 4.1 session cookie in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’m attempting to strangle a legacy Rails 4.1 application by using a proxy in front of it and sending some requests to a new Rails 6 application.

The Rails 4 application is responsible for user authentication and setting the initial session cookie.

Is there a way to get the Rails 6 application to read/write Rails 4.1 compatible session cookies?

Thanks

Comment: I'd expect the tricky part is the writing rather than reading. Perusing the upgrade docs, I see breaking changes to signed/encrypted cookies in [Rails 5.2](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#expiry-in-signed-or-encrypted-cookie-is-now-embedded-in-the-cookies-values) and [Rails 6](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#purpose-in-signed-or-encrypted-cookie-is-now-embedded-within-cookies). Both have config options to allow you to disable for reading by older versions. I haven't done it myself, so I can't testify, but it's a place to start anyway.

Comment: Thanks @rmlockerd -- yes, that's where I started. It'd be nice to find someone who has managed to do this so I can figure out if it is possible. I mean, without rewriting the Rails 4 handler in Rails 6.

Comment: @TimHarding Any updates, did it work? I'm trying to do the same thing almost. Any suggestions? If you can answer your question here, it will great.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to write an answer here as I recently had to dig through some Rails guts to solve this issue. First, make sure both apps share the same `secret_key_base`, cookie domain, and cookie key. This will let the apps at least read the same session cookie:

```rb
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {
  domain: 'myapp.com',   # can omit if they're on the same domain
  key: '_myapp_session', # need to be explicit here
  expire_after: 60.minutes
}
```

Then, you need to make sure both apps can read the actual payload. The default cookie serialization is moving to JSON in Rails 7, but any older version will still default to `:marshal` (which uses the basic Ruby Marshal module). Make sure you're using the same serializer.

```
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :marshal
```

Lastly, if your newer app is Rails 6.2+, be warned that Rails started wrapping all cookie payloads (regardless of serialization method) in a JSON envelope. This envelope **can't** be opened by Rails 4.2 or older apps. So your session can move from Rails 4.2 -> 6.2, but not back...

Unless you monkeypatch it with a custom deserializer, like so:

```rb
class WrappedSerializer
  def self.base_serializer
    Marshal # or JSON, if you're using :json above
  end

  def self.load(value)
    # if this is a Rails 4-created session, parsing will fail & hit the rescue
    json = JSON.parse(value) rescue nil

    return base_serializer.load(value) if json.nil? || !json.key?('_rails')

    base_serializer.load(Base64.decode64(json.dig('_rails', 'message')))
  end

  def self.dump(value)
    base_serializer.dump(value)
  end
end

module ActionDispatch
  class Cookies
    module SerializedCookieJars
      def serializer
        WrappedSerializer
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I should point out that, because this strips the envelope which might contain a custom expiry time, the Rails 5.2+ feature of being able to set custom expiry times will not work for any sessions that transition back to your Rails 4 app. If you use that feature, you could probably find a way change the above serializer to rewrap the payload when it deserializes.